# This movie requires Quicktime, which is not supported by this version of iTunes

Tags: itunes, quicktime

Running Yosemite 10.10.3 on a late 2009 iMac. I've tried switching iTunes to run in 32-bit mode but to no avail. I was wondering if anyone else had this problem or solution? (This happens when I want to watch iTunes University courses)

Comment: bit more information please, what version of itunes, what version of QuickTime

Comment: Which iTunes University courses? And how did you switch to 32bit mode?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't all versions of iTunes support QT MOV video? Or you can try to save the QuickTime movie to MP4 and then add into itunes, that works for me.